# How can I execute same scenario or feature 10 times concurrently in multiple browser to check the performance of website

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir, ruby-jmeter

I have a requirement for the performance of webpage, 
example : I have a logging page need to run 10 concurrent execution with different users to test the performance of that page.

I have gone through ruby-jmeter gem but It opened only one browser, but in jmeter log it is showing more than 10 sessions.

Can anyone help on this one

Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to test with 10 different browser instances that running 10 concurrent sessions doesn't accomplish? Unless you're doing automated UI testing, in which case jmeter isn't what you'd use, what you're doing should be what you need.

Comment: example: i have a login page, I would like to test this  page with 10 concurrent users in 10 IE instances at a time, is it possible to do with ruby-jmeter and selenium

Comment: I have not followed these steps to know if they actually work, but this should get you started: https://www.swtestacademy.com/performance-testing-jmeter-selenium-grid/

Answer (score 0):

To run multiple sessions simultaneously you can use the parallel tests gem: https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests/

Standard disclaimer: there are a lot of variables in evaluating performance and it is extremely difficult to control those variables sufficiently to get useful information on performance using Selenium or Watir.

Comment: This parallel_test, I cannot run the same scenario for 10 times or 50 times at a time. is it possible with parallel _tests?

Comment: any help on this

Comment: Create a rake task that does `50.times { ... }`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I think rake will not execute tests in parallel manner :-)